# find all in mongoose

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose

I have Schema With name **score**, and that have an `iduser: req.session.user._id`.
and I have more than one items with same iduser. I wanna to find all the items with the same iduser. and I use the
`var users = await storescors16.find({ id })`  `id = res.session.user._id`.
but that show me all the items in **score** !

My code

//schema

```
const storescor = new mongoose.Schema({
        iduser: String,
        level: { type: String, default: null },
        day: { type: String, default: null },
        date: { type: String, default: null },
        time: { type: String, default: null },
        objectif: { type: String, default: null }
    })

    var storescors16 = mongoose.model("storescor", storescor);

//post infos to database
    router.post('/control/edite-control', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.session.selectuserid);
        var { level, day, date, time, ob } = req.body
        var scor = new storescors16({
            iduser: req.session.selectuserid,
            level: level,
            day: day,
            date: date,
            time: time,
            objectif: ob,
        })

//read infos from databse
    router.get('/result', auth, async(req, res) => {
        var id = req.session.user._id
    
        console.log(id);
    
        var user = User.findById(id, (err, docs) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log();
        })
    
        var ids = req.session.user._id
    
        var notes = await storescors16.find({ ids })
        console.log(notes);
    
        let scor = user.quiz
        res.render('./options/result', {
            notes: notes,
            scor: scor,
            title: 'سجل درجات النجم',
            name: session.user.name,
            email: session.user.email,
    
        })
    });
```

> I use nodejs as backend

Comment: Would be great if you add schema and code here.

Comment: okay that well. I added my code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all use findAll function with where.

```js
const users = await storescors16.findAll({ id });
```

That if I understand you currect.

Comment: All users with the same name "iduser". that code blow in desc